# Swift, what project settings and configuration code do I need to use a Objective C CocoaPod with swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've previously setup an Objective C framework which works fine with an Objective C project, which also works fine that I've migrated to my own private pod.

I have read various posts about debugger issues, perhaps needing to add the framework to a sub folder. Also that a bridging header is required and normal Objective C imports should be added.

In my own experience I have found it less than perfect and can not get class instance properties to show in the debugger. Seeing ObjectiveC.NSObject instead.

I also have issues with strings not being passed correctly to Objective C methods in the framework and the values aren't visible. I'm also getting errors accessing these strings.

I really need to know what's possible, what I should be seeing, what steps I need to follow and how I should proceed to gain help.

It seems like there are bugs in Xcode, that values aren't transformed correctly.

I'm left feeling that I'm going to have quite a lot of changes to make to my Objective C framework, which is rather disappointing.

I'm also quite new to swift and this has cast doubt on what I've learnt.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Objective-c cocoapods in a Swift project you need to create a bridging header which you will use to import any Objective-c classes you want to expose to Swift.

You should have been prompted if you want a bridging-header file at some point, but if you declined you can create one manually following these steps: [manually create a bridging header](https://mycodetips.com/ios/manually-adding-swift-bridging-header-1290.html)

Comment: I have created one and I don’t get any errors when initially assigning class instance variables.